# Which three-letter time zone IDs are not deprecated?

Tags: java, timezone

There is a deprecation warning in the [Javadoc of `TimeZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html):

> For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are also supported. However, their use is deprecated...

It says "other" here, but I can't see where it defines which three-letter IDs are non-deprecated. Are these documented anywhere?

`GMT` is mentioned in the doc as the fallback, so it's safe to assume that's one of non-deprecated IDs; but:

- Is `UTC` deprecated? Are you meant to use `Etc/UTC` instead? Or should you be using `GMT`? (`TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC").hasSameRules(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")` is true)
- Is `CET` (Central European Time) deprecated? If not, what time zone identifier are you supposed to use instead? According to [this demo](http://ideone.com/cXxbPt), there is only one other identifier yielding the same rules, which is `MET` (Middle European Time).

  There is another timezone ID, `ECT`, which has the same display name as `CET` (Central European Time), but which doesn't have the same rules (I think they differ somewhere in the mid 1970s), which has the same rules as `Europe/Paris`. But, since they have different rules, the two are not interchangable.

So, my conclusion from this is that the minimal set of supported three-letter IDs is `GMT` and `CET`; but it seems odd that is not documented. Any ideas?

---

I note the possible duplicate suggested by @shmosel: [Is "GMT" an Abbreviation in Java TimeZone and if So is it OK to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766352/is-gmt-an-abbreviation-in-java-timezone-and-if-so-is-it-ok-to-use-it). That partly covers my question; but I'm asking the more general question "what is supported (and how do we know that)", rather than just "is X supported".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is "GMT" an Abbreviation in Java TimeZone and if So is it OK to use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766352/is-gmt-an-abbreviation-in-java-timezone-and-if-so-is-it-ok-to-use-it)

Comment: @shmosel that's a reasonable part of the answer, but I'm not sure it quite covers it - that's only really asking whether `GMT` is valid, which it is, because it's mentioned in the doc. It's not addressing the questions of UTC or CET, which are (at least to some extent) separate.

Comment: I would expect UTC to be supported since it is also a so-named constant in `ZoneOffset` (`java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC`) (not in `ZoneId`, though) (and it still isn’t a full answer to the question).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, to answer your specific questions:

1. All abbreviation-based identifiers should be considered deprecated.  They are not sufficient to identify a particular time zone with all detail retained.  For example, you can see all the locations that use Central European Time [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cet).  Some of them use `CET` all year long, and some of them use `CET` in the winter but `CEST` in the summer.  Of those, not all of them use the same DST transition days, or have the same time zone offsets throughout their history.  There's just not enough information in `CET` to decide which set of rules to use.
2. It is relatively safe to use `GMT` or `UTC`, as these are unambiguous.  However it would be more correct to use `Etc/GMT` or `Etc/UTC`.  If you were to pick just one, IMHO it should be `Etc/UTC`.
3. `CET` should be considered deprecated, along with other abbreviations, as I mentioned.  However, it's worth noting that *some* abbreviations (like `CET`) come from the TZ Database, and some (like `AST`) come from legacy of Java.  This distinction is important, as only the TZDB ones are useful in data that may be transmitted elsewhere and interpreted by non-Java based systems.

   Of particular note, recognize that the US abbreviations `PST` and `CST` are *NOT* in the TZDB, even though `MST` and `EST` *are*.
4. Instead of `CET`, you should pick which locality-based time zone is relevant to your scenario.  If you are talking about France, use `Europe/Paris`.  If you are talking about Poland, use `Europe/Warsaw`, etc.

Next, understand that the underlying [TZ Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) has several types of identifiers that are acceptable to use:

- Location based, in the form of `Area/Locality`

  - Ex:  `America/New_York`, `Europe/London`, `Pacific/Honolulu`
- Location based, in the form of `Area/Region/Locality`

  - Ex: `America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires`, `America/Indiana/Knox`
- Administrative zones, in the `Etc` namespace:

  - Ex:  `Etc/UTC`, `Etc/GMT+2`,  `Etc/GMT-5`
  - +/- are based on POSIX standards, opposite of the typically expected ISO standard
  - Commonly used for ships at sea

It also has several forms that are an artifact of history, and should *NOT* be used any more:

- Location based, in the form of `Country` or `Country/StateOrRegion`

  - Ex: `US/Pacific`, `US/Hawaii`, `Brazil/East`, `Canada/Newfoundland`, `Egypt`, `Cuba`
- POSIX identifiers in the continental US:

  - Ex: `EST5EDT`, `CST6CDT`, `MST7MDT`, `PST8PDT`
- Abbreviations - *some of them anyway*

  - Ex:  `EST`, `EET`, `PRC`, `WET`

Additionally, Java had previously extended these identifiers to include additional abbreviations that are *NOT* part of the TZ Database.  I was able to find them listed [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8149811), as links to their corresponding TZ Database modern identifiers:

```
Link Australia/Darwin ACT 
Link Australia/Sydney AET 
Link America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires AGT 
Link Africa/Cairo ART 
Link America/Anchorage AST 
Link America/Sao_Paulo BET 
Link Asia/Dhaka BST 
Link Africa/Harare CAT 
Link America/St_Johns CNT 
Link America/Chicago CST 
Link Asia/Shanghai CTT 
Link Africa/Addis_Ababa EAT 
Link Europe/Paris ECT 
Link America/New_York EST 
Link Pacific/Honolulu HST 
Link America/Indianapolis IET 
Link Asia/Calcutta IST 
Link Asia/Tokyo JST 
Link Pacific/Apia MIT 
Link America/Denver MST 
Link Asia/Yerevan NET 
Link Pacific/Auckland NST 
Link Asia/Karachi PLT 
Link America/Phoenix PNT 
Link America/Puerto_Rico PRT 
Link America/Los_Angeles PST 
Link Pacific/Guadalcanal SST 
Link Asia/Saigon VST
```

Of course, these mappings may or may not be opinionated - but they are reportedly the ones used by Java's TZUpdater tool to carry forward support for these legacy Java time zone abbreviations.

Comment: Fine post so far but what I stumble about is your preference for Etc/*-notation. What is your reason to say it "would be more correct"? I would prefer ISO-notation (especially because of sign handling), even UTC or UTC+00:00 instead of Etc/UTC. Although Etc/UTC (or Etc/GMT) does not explicitly use signs it might confuse users when they are else told not to use Etc-notation because of opposite and unexpected signs.

Comment: I would say they are "more correct" only with regards to which TZDB identifiers you should use.  Though, I admit - I often just use `UTC` - but it is a link in the "backward" file in the TZDB, and thus the `Etc/UTC` version is probably more correct.  I do agree with you about preferring the style `UTC+00:00` with regard to display of time zone offset, just not for TZDB identifiers.

Comment: As far as `Etc/GMT` - I think there are still plenty of people who prefer the abbreviation "GMT", but IMHO it makes more sense to use "UTC" - since it has a scientific definition instead of just a legal/civil one.

Comment: I see. Well, I am rather at home in Java world. And here we often just use offsets instead of TZDB identifiers which are effectively only offsets, too - like these Etc/GMT...identifiers. Every relevant Java-API enables users to directly pass offsets like TZDB-identifiers. Maybe it is different in other programming environments.

Comment: @MenoHochschild - Sure, but according to [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html), "If the time zone you want is not represented by one of the supported IDs, then a custom time zone ID can be specified to produce a TimeZone."  Therefore, I'd say it is preferred to provide an ID.  This makes sense especially with regard to time zones that alternate between offsets for DST.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [ZoneId](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) could be used as reference.

```
ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().stream()
        .filter(z -> z.length() == 3)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

output

```
GMT
CET
UTC
ROK
MET
PRC
WET
UCT
EET
```

If you call `ZoneId.of("CST")` it throws

```
java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException: Unknown time-zone ID: CST
```

Comment: I am not asking how to get all 3-letter zones; I am asking which of the three-letter supported zones *are not deprecated*.

Comment: @AndyTurner Just after posting my anser I felt that I could misread your question. Please have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Your edit is much better. I think you can delete the first half of your answer.