# Different timezone id for the same short timezone name

Tags: java, zoneddatetime

I have a string `"02:00:00 Feb 05, 2023 PST"` which I parse:

```java
ZonedDateTime d = ZonedDateTime.parse(nextPaymentDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:m:s MMM d, uuuu z"));
```

Comparing it a constructed date:

```java
ZonedDateTime expectedDate = ZonedDateTime.of(2023, 2, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of(ZoneId.SHORT_IDS.get("PST")));
```

fails, because:

```
Expected :2023-02-05T02:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
Actual   :2023-02-05T02:00-08:00[America/Tijuana]
```

Setting exact timezone id (e.g. fixing `America/Tijuana`) does not work, as the timezone is parsed differently on another machine (as `America/Los_Angeles` instead of `America/Tijuana` like on my machine).

How can I assert the dates are equal in this case?

Comment: So you want to compare the actual time they identify? Then convert them to `Instant` and compare those.

Comment: Related: [IST mapped to wrong ZoneId in java.time library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57733849/ist-mapped-to-wrong-zoneid-in-java-time-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time zone abbreviations used by Java when parsing depend on the locale, so you cannot compare the result to a fixed value. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59386011/1374678).

I would convert the `ZonedDateTime` objects to `OffsetDateTime` before comparing them, or even to `Instant`, as Joachim suggested.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I suggest you ask the publisher of your data to avoid using abbreviated timezone IDs. In most cases, these abbreviations are 3 characters long but they may be 2 or 4 characters long (e.g. [CT](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ct) and [AEST](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/aest)) as commented by [Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75321780/different-timezone-id-for-the-same-short-timezone-name/75326361?noredirect=1#comment132916764_75326361).

Given below is a note from the Java 7 `Timezone` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html):

> #### Three-letter time zone IDs
>
> For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are
> also supported. However, **their use is deprecated** because the same
> abbreviation is often used for multiple time zones (for example, "CST"
> could be U.S. "Central Standard Time" and "China Standard Time"), and
> the Java platform can then only recognize one of them.

There is already a good [suggestion by Joachim Sauer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75321780/different-timezone-id-for-the-same-short-timezone-name#comment132908307_75321780). Alternatively, you can retrieve the `ZoneId` from the parsed date-time and use it while constructing your `ZonedDateTime`.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:m:s MMM d, uuuu z", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String strNextPaymentDate = "02:00:00 Feb 05, 2023 PST";
        ZonedDateTime zdtNextPaymentDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(strNextPaymentDate, parser);
        ZonedDateTime zdtExpectedDate = ZonedDateTime.of(2023, 2, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, zdtNextPaymentDate.getZone());
        System.out.println(zdtNextPaymentDate);
        System.out.println(zdtExpectedDate);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2023-02-05T02:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
2023-02-05T02:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/bRYRBE)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Actually, those pseudo zones can be 2-4 characters long, not just 3. Examples: [CT](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ct) and [AEST](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/aest).