# Spark 3.0 UTC to AKST conversion fails with ZoneRulesException: Unknown time-zone ID

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am not able to convert timestamps in UTC to AKST timezone in Spark 3.0. The same works in Spark 2.4. All other conversions work (to EST, PST, MST etc).

Appreciate any inputs on how to fix this error.

Below command:

```scala
spark.sql("select from_utc_timestamp('2020-10-01 11:12:30', 'AKST')").show
```

returns the error:

> java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException: Unknown time-zone ID: AKST

Detailed log:

```
java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException: Unknown time-zone ID: AKST
  at java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider.getProvider(ZoneRulesProvider.java:272)
  at java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider.getRules(ZoneRulesProvider.java:227)
  at java.time.ZoneRegion.ofId(ZoneRegion.java:120)
  at java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:411)
  at java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:359)
  at java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:315)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.getZoneId(DateTimeUtils.scala:62)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.fromUTCTime(DateTimeUtils.scala:833)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.FromUTCTimestamp.nullSafeEval(datetimeExpressions.scala:1299)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BinaryExpression.eval(Expression.scala:552)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnaryExpression.eval(Expression.scala:457)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConstantFolding$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.applyOrElse(expressions.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConstantFolding$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.applyOrElse(expressions.scala:45)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$1(TreeNode.scala:321)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:72)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:321)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:326)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.applyFunctionIfChanged$1(TreeNode.scala:380)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:416)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:248)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:414)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:326)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.$anonfun$transformExpressionsDown$1(QueryPlan.scala:96)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.$anonfun$mapExpressions$1(QueryPlan.scala:118)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:72)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpression$1(QueryPlan.scala:118)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:129)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.$anonfun$mapExpressions$3(QueryPlan.scala:134)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:298)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:134)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.$anonfun$mapExpressions$4(QueryPlan.scala:139)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:248)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.mapExpressions(QueryPlan.scala:139)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsDown(QueryPlan.scala:96)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConstantFolding$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(expressions.scala:45)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConstantFolding$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(expressions.scala:44)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$1(TreeNode.scala:321)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:72)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:321)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:149)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:147)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:326)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.applyFunctionIfChanged$1(TreeNode.scala:380)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:416)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:248)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:414)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:326)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:149)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:147)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:326)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.applyFunctionIfChanged$1(TreeNode.scala:380)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:416)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:248)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:414)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:326)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:149)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:147)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:310)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConstantFolding$.apply(expressions.scala:44)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConstantFolding$.apply(expressions.scala:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:149)
  at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
  at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:89)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:146)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:138)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:138)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:116)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:98)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:116)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$optimizedPlan$1(QueryExecution.scala:82)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:153)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:763)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:153)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:82)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$writePlans$4(QueryExecution.scala:217)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$.append(QueryPlan.scala:381)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$QueryExecution$$writePlans(QueryExecution.scala:217)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toString(QueryExecution.scala:227)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:96)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:207)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:88)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:763)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3653)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2737)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2944)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:301)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:338)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:864)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:823)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:832)
  ... 47 elided
```

Comment: Most of Alaska used summer time (AKDT, Alaska Daylight Time) until November 1, 2020. Are you serious about wanting standard time, 2020-10-01 11:12:30 AKST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it can't understand `AKST`, but Spark 3 seems to understand `America/Anchorage`, which I suppose to have the timezone `AKST`:

```
spark.sql("select from_utc_timestamp('2020-10-01 11:12:30', 'America/Anchorage')").show
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding further to mck's answer. You are using the old Java data-time API zone's short IDs. According to this Databricks blog post [A Comprehensive Look at Dates and Timestamps in Apache Spark™ 3.0](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/07/22/a-comprehensive-look-at-dates-and-timestamps-in-apache-spark-3-0.html), Spark migrated to the new API since version 3.0:

> Since Java 8, the JDK has exposed a new API for date-time manipulation
> and time zone offset resolution, and Spark migrated to this new API in
> version 3.0. Although the mapping of time zone names to offsets has
> the same source, IANA TZDB, it is implemented differently in Java 8
> and higher versus Java 7.

You can verify it by opening spark-shell and list available zones like this:

```scala
import java.time.ZoneId
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

ZoneId.SHORT_IDS.asScala.keys

//res0: Iterable[String] = Set(CTT, ART, CNT, PRT, PNT, PLT, AST, BST, CST, EST, HST, JST, IST, AGT, NST, MST, AET, BET, PST, ACT, SST, VST, CAT, ECT, EAT, IET, MIT, NET)
```

That said, you should not use abbreviations when you specify timezones, instead use `area/city` format. See [Which three-letter time zone IDs are not deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41672825/which-three-letter-time-zone-ids-are-not-deprecated)